# Powershell stop multiple applications and processes on the remote servers

Tags: powershell, process, remote-server

```
Function StopApplication{

Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string[]] $Servers,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName="ServiceNames")]
    [string[]] $ServiceNames,
    [Parameter()]
    [PSCredential] $Cred
)     
       foreach ($server in $Servers)
      {

     $stop = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_process -ComputerName $Server | Where-Object {$_.ProcessName -match $ServiceName}
     $stop.terminate()
       }
}
```

I am trying to write a powershell script to stop multiple processes on remote servers.  What would be the best way to do this? should I create a powershell session? use invoke-command or just use get-wmiobject?

Comment: My luck has been best played in the win32_process terminate() method like you are doing.